# What are the arguments to say that there is a non-democratic government in Venezuela?

Tags: election, democracy, presidential-election, venezuela, dictatorship

After the recent presidential elections in Venezuela on May 20th, despite lots of international and neutral observers, most media keep saying that the elections were corrupted.

Besides, most media keep saying that the government in Venezuela is anti-democratic, like a dictatorship.

I can't figure out what are the arguments for this kind of statement.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a media report which makes claims without satisfactorily backing it up?

Answer (score 6):

[This article](https://panampost.com/pedro-garcia/2015/07/08/10-reasons-why-venezuela-is-not-a-democracy/?cn-reloaded=1) tries to cover the reasons you are looking for:

- **non-transparent elections**:

> Nicolás Maduro won the presidential election by a small margin
>   compared with the number of invalid votes. This dubious outcome led
>   opposition leaders to request an audit of the vote.
>
> The audit took place, but not under the conditions the opposition
>   demanded.

- **weak separation of powers**:

> nation’s top court has sided with the government in all 9,000 cases
>   between 2006 and 2014 involving disputes between the state and
>   citizens.

- **diminishing freedom of expression**:

> the country’s main broadcasting network, RCTV, was forced to shut down
>   when the government refused to extend its license, and independent
>   reporting has slowly disappeared since. It is now practically
>   impossible to find traditional media that dare to criticize the
>   regime.

These are only a few reasons and the article argues also about small economical liberty, property rights issues, privacy issues, lack of checks upon executive branch.

If you are looking for a more official source, [US Embassy in Venezuela](https://ve.usembassy.gov/anti-democratic-actions-maduro-regime-venezuela-november-7-2017/) also emphasizes democracy issues:

> The United States condemns the Maduro regime’s increasing **disrespect
>   for democracy and fundamental human rights in Venezuela**. By
>   attempting **to strip the democratically elected National Assembly’s
>   Vice President and opposition leader Freddy Guevara of his
>   parliamentary immunity and barring him from leaving the country**, the
>   regime is pursuing yet another extreme measure to **close the
>   democratic space in Venezuela, criminalize dissent, and control
>   information.**